# When should NodeAtPoint method return SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I have an iOS app, written with SpriteKit.
It uses 4 `SKShapeNode` elements to determine which part of the screen the user taps in.
All these elements are triangles and they split the screen like a big X.
They are created using `CGPath`, which draws a triangle.
To determine if the user tapped in the node I use scene method - `NodeAtPoint`.

In iOS 8.4 everything worked as expected: when I tap inside the triangle, `NodeAtPoint` returns the `SKShapeNode` I just tapped.

In iOS 9.0 `NodeAtPoint` returns the `SKShapeNode` even if I tap outside its bounds, but inside the bounds of rectangle in which my `SKShapeNode` fits into.

So my question is: How should `NodeAtPoint` method work for `SKShapeNode`?

1. It returns the `SKShapeNode` if the Point is inside its shape.
2. It returns the `SKShapeNode` if the Point is inside its frame.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/nodeAtPoint:
`SKNode`'s `nodeAtPoint` function always returns an `SKNode`. You can then cast `SKShapeNode` to the `SKNode`. To answer your other question the frame is calculated using the `calculateAccumulatedFrame` function. You can see that here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/calculateAccumulatedFrame
So you might do something like this:

```
if let node = scene.nodeAtPoint(CGPointMake(0,0)) as? SKShapeNode {
//do whatever
}
```

Comment: Well, according to documentation, if I have SKShapeNode initialized from CGPath: (0,0);(scene.width/2, scene.height/2);(scene.width, 0). Then its accumulated frame = rectangle with left bottom point = (0,0) and right top point = (scene.width, scene.height/2). But I believe that s not how it worked in ios 8.4.

Comment: I double checked it: If you run your app in 8.4 simulator and you click outside the triangle, nodeAtPoint doesn't return triangle SKShapeNode. Although both frame and calculateAccumulatedFrame return half screen rectangle. So I guess it was error in 8.4 which they have fixed in 9.0. But if someone like me relied on this behavior it could break his app.